# Irregular error from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

About every 1 in 10 runs I get an error (KeyError: 0) from pandas when running this line:

```
[rnd.choice(indepVar[t]) for t in setTimes]
```

where `indepVar` is a DataFrame(100,21) and `setTimes` is a tuple of three integers (1,10,20). Most of the times it gives me a list of three randomly chosen numbers from indepVar. When the error occurs I get error log as below.

Can someone point out to me, what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Error log (environment anaconda 4.3):

```
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\random.py", line 258, in choice
return seq[i]

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 603, in __getitem__
result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2169, in get_value
tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))

File "pandas\index.pyx", line 98, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3557)

File "pandas\index.pyx", line 106, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3240)

File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4279)

File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 404, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:8564)

File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 410, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:8508)

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: We probably need to see `indepVar` and `setTimes` for one of the cases where the code fails.

Comment: Can you share head of indepVar?

Comment: indepVar is a bunch of (more or less) random numbers within 0.2 and -0.2.

Comment: @Pintu - you can find the head of indepVar here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4787689/head%20of%20indepVar.txt

Comment: @Ianguitar - I tried to catch the exact params when it fails with the debugger, but through repeated loops the code worked. Then when I let it run without debugger it crashed after a (seemingly random) number of iterations.